# NavigateURL string format

Tags: c#, string-concatenation, navigateurl

I have looked to all the similar questions but is still not able to get it to work:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Phones/DisplayPhoneDetails.aspx?SelectedPhoneMacAddr={0}", selectedCCMUserDetailled.primaryDevice.Value.ToString())%>'><%= selectedCCMUserDetailled.primaryDevice.Value %></asp:HyperLink>
```

This generates:

```
<a id="MainContent_HyperLink2">CSFD4SIG</a>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why do not set the url from page_load for example?

Comment: Hi, yes, because the links are generated inside a listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use <%%> in < asp: tag attribute

you can try use html tag like < a >

and to do this .below is my example

```
<a href=<%# String.Format("'~/Phones/DisplayPhoneDetails.aspx?SelectedPhoneMacAddr={0}'", selectedCCMUserDetailled.primaryDevice.Value.ToString())%>><%= selectedCCMUserDetailled.primaryDevice.Value %></a>
```